# Is the NSF file structure documentation available anywhere online?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am looking for NSF file structure.
Can anyone send me link where i would find information about it.

Comment: Why do you want it?  Perhaps we could help answer a specific question you have about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no published file format for Notes NSF files, but there are a number of options available for accessing data within an NSF, including:

- Lotus C and C++ API's (you can
  download toolkits [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/downloads/toolkits.html?S_TACT=105AGX13&S_CMP=LSDL)) . The C API - provides access to everything there
  is in an NSF - documents, design
  elements, security elements, etc)
- DXL (Domino XML) - you can extract the
  design and data as XML
- ODBC using the Notes SQL driver
- Java API (does not
  expose everything in the NSF) -
  documentation is [here](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359850.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/25b460352ed150ba8525731b004a9f0b?OpenDocument)
- COM interface - documentation is [here](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2359850.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/16d78c3f9148e7eb8525731b0049e880?OpenDocument)

Comment: Thanks! Does C API works under Linux , do i need to install Lotus Notes Domino server to use it ?

Comment: The Notes C API is available on UNIX. You need to have either the Notes client or the Domino server installed on the platform. You can download C API kit from here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/downloads/toolkits.html

Comment: There's a C parser with no dependency on the Notes C API: https://github.com/libyal/libnsfdb

Answer (score 2):

It's not documented - you are supposed to use the Lotus Notes API to access these files. Very often the files (or parts of them) are encrypted.