# How to read Lotus Notes mail archives (*.nsf)

Tags: c#, java, c++, lotus-notes, file-format

Does anyone know how to read these files without using the interops or COM interaction?  Just the direct way. Is there any spec of this format or reverse engineered stuff that could help on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is Lotus API (which is in C). It provides access to everything there is in an NSF - documents, design elements, security elements, etc) 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/downloads/toolkits.html?S_TACT=105AGX13&S_CMP=LSDL

Read all you choices here:
[Is the NSF file structure documentation available anywhere online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315404/is-the-nsf-file-structure-documentation-available-anywhere-online)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Notes C API or Notes C++ API interfaces to read that files. But corresponding DLL's distributed with Notes client. File format is named ODS.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you just need to "read" the files, manually, there is the Notes client. There is a free (trial) download of the latest client here->

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/lsndad/?S_TACT=105AGX13&S_CMP=NANDD

Comment: Hi, thanks, but i have to read it without any 3d party tools, just with own code.